# biblatex remove the eng. from citations

Tags: biblatex

I am new with `biblatex` and I would like to format my citation such that:
1. The citations appear without the ***eng.*** that appears in each reference.
2. The names appear as Smith, J.S.
as opposed to J S Smith

An example of my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[style=numeric,subentry,maxnames=5]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\addbibresource{../../bibliographies/shivBiblio}

\begin{document}
this is an example \cite{perelson1996}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and I get the following:

this is an example [1]

> References
>
> [1] A S Perelson, A U Neumann, M Markowitz, J M Leonard,
>   and D D Ho. “HIV-1 dynamics in vivo: virion clearance rate, infected
>   cell life-span, and viral generation time.” **eng.** Science 271.5255
>   (1996), pp. 1582–1586. ISSN: 0036-8075 (Print); 0036-8075 (Linking).

Here is the original bibTex reference:

```
@article{perelson1996,
Abstract = {A new mathematical model was used to analyze a detailed set of human immunodeficiency virus-type 1 (HIV-1) viral load data collected from five infected individuals after the administration of a potent inhibitor of HIV-1 protease. Productively infected cells were estimated to have, on average, a life-span of 2.2 days (half-life t 1/2 = 1.6 days), and plasma virions were estimated to have a mean life-span of 0.3 days (t 1/2 = 0.24 days). The estimated average total HIV-1 production was 10.3 x 10(9) virions per day, which is substantially greater than previous minimum estimates. The results also suggest that the minimum duration of the HIV-1 life cycle in vivo is 1.2 days on average, and that the average HIV-1 generation time--defined as the time from release of a virion until it infects another cell and causes the release of a new generation of viral particles--is 2.6 days. These findings on viral dynamics provide not only a kinetic picture of HIV-1 pathogenesis, but also theoretical principles to guide the development of treatment strategies.},
Address = {Theoretical Division, Los Alamos National Laboratory, NM 87545, USA.},
Author = {Perelson, A S and Neumann, A U and Markowitz, M and Leonard, J M and Ho, D D},
Crdt = {1996/03/15 00:00},
Da = {19960425},
Date = {1996 Mar 15},
Date-Added = {2013-06-28 00:45:32 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2013-06-28 21:27:14 +0000},
Dcom = {19960425},
Edat = {1996/03/15},
Gr = {AI27742/AI/NIAID NIH HHS/United States; N01 AI45218/AI/NIAID NIH HHS/United States; RR06555/RR/NCRR NIH HHS/United States; etc.},
Issn = {0036-8075 (Print); 0036-8075 (Linking)},
Jid = {0404511},
Journal = {Science},
Jt = {Science (New York, N.Y.)},
Language = {eng},
Lr = {20071114},
Mh = {Antiviral Agents/administration \& dosage/therapeutic use; CD4 Lymphocyte Count; CD4-Positive T-Lymphocytes/*cytology/*virology; Cell Survival; HIV Infections/drug therapy/*virology; HIV Protease Inhibitors/administration \& dosage/therapeutic use; HIV-1/drug effects/*physiology; Half-Life; Humans; Kinetics; Models, Biological; RNA, Viral/blood; Regression Analysis; Ritonavir; Thiazoles/administration \& dosage/therapeutic use; Valine/administration \& dosage/analogs \& derivatives/therapeutic use; Viremia; Virion/drug effects/*physiology; Virus Replication},
Mhda = {1996/03/15 00:01},
Month = {Mar},
Number = {5255},
Own = {NLM},
Pages = {1582--1586},
Pl = {UNITED STATES},
Pmid = {8599114},
Pst = {ppublish},
Pt = {Journal Article; Research Support, Non-U.S. Gov't; Research Support, U.S. Gov't, Non-P.H.S.; Research Support, U.S. Gov't, P.H.S.},
Rn = {0 (Antiviral Agents); 0 (HIV Protease Inhibitors); 0 (RNA, Viral); 0 (Ritonavir); 0 (Thiazoles); 7004-03-7 (Valine)},
Sb = {IM; X},
Source = {Science. 1996 Mar 15;271(5255):1582-6.},
Status = {MEDLINE},
Title = {{HIV-1 dynamics in vivo: virion clearance rate, infected cell life-span, and viral generation time.}},
Volume = {271},
Year = {1996}}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.sx  I've formatted your code sample for you (you can format code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` icon.)  Can you post the `bibtex` source of the bibliography entry itself (just this one entry).

Comment: Hi @AlanMunn, so if I go and search for the .bbl file created by biblatex, it is a very long file (I cannot post it here)...

Comment: Hi @AlanMunn, so if I go and search for the .bbl file created by biblatex, it is a very long file (I cannot post it here)...
I use BibDesk to create my bibliography. If I use plain bibTex, then the bibtex source code will be the following:
\bibitem{perelson1996}
A.~S. Perelson, A.~U. Neumann, M.~Markowitz, J.~M. Leonard, and D.~D. Ho,
  ``{HIV-1 dynamics in vivo: virion clearance rate, infected cell life-span,
  and viral generation time.},'' {\em Science}, vol.~271, pp.~1582--1586, Mar
  1996.

PS: I don't see the icon for formatting code in a comment :( :(

Comment: In BibDesk select the reference and then in the edit menu choose "Copy as  BibTeX record" and then edit your question and paste it (formatted as code).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `biblatex` package is quite daunting, but many things are relatively easy to modify if you know where to look.  One really useful resource is this question:

- [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/2693)

Most of my answer is contained in that answer, although I also have some experience writing my own `biblatex` styles.

The reason you are getting the `eng.` field is that your `.bib` entries have a *lot* of extra fields in them, and `biblatex` will print many of them if it recognizes them.  In this case the `eng` is the `language` field.  To remove this we use:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearlist{language}%
}
```

To change the order of names and initials we need to declare a `NameAlias` for the `default` sorting scheme that is used by numeric bibliography schemes.

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
```

Finally to change the use of initials with punctuation, we add a package option:

```
[firstinits=true]
```

So the final code is (I also removed unnecessary packages from the example.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,subentry,maxnames=5,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \clearlist{language}%
}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\addbibresource{<your-bibfile>.bib}

\begin{document}
this is an example \cite{perelson1996}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you very much @AlanMunn ! this worked perfectly :)