# Prevent biblatex from printing the language name and use language only for hyphenation

Tags: biblatex, languages, hyphenation, babel, biber

In my `.bib`-file the `language` field is filled out in all entries.

As MWE, they all look (as expected) like:

```
@Collection{Bakker:Grammar,
  editor =   {Egbert J[an] Bakker},
  gender =   {sm},
  title =    {Grammar as Interpretation},
  subtitle = {Greek Literature in its Linguistic Context},
  shorttitle = {Grammar},
  language = {english},
  year =     1997,
  series =   {Mnemosyne. Supplementum},
  number =   171,
  publisher = {Brill},
  location ={Leiden AND New York AND K{\"o}ln}
  }
```

To print the bibliogeaphy I created this file

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,twoside,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\input{ix-utf8enc.dfu}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{gfsdidot,gfsporson}
\savesymbol{og}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,greek,italian,frenchb,english,british,german]{babel}
\usepackage[GlyphNames,boldLipsian]{teubner}
\savesymbol{breve}
\savesymbol{aa}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\restoresymbol{pplj}{breve}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[scaled=.9]{DejaVuSansCondensed}
\Lipsiantrue
\ifFamily{pplj}{porson}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=german, german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern, sortlocale=de_DE,
            sorting=nyvt, autolang=hyphen, alldates=terse,
            annotation=true, useprefix=true, language=ngerman,
             datezeros=false,  bibencoding=auto, pagetracker=spread,
             publocformat= loccolonpub, backend=biber, 
             citetracker = constrict, ibidtracker=constrict,
             opcittracker=constrict, idemtracker=constrict,
             relatedformat=parens,  clearlang=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{moredefs}
\usepackage{lips}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[twothirds,nonegthinspace]{thinsp}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
```

After compiling it with `biber --bblsafechars mybib` and `latex mybib.tex` I get

Bakker, Egbert J[an]

1997   *Hrsg.*, *Grammar as Interpretation*. Greek Literature in its Linguistic Context, Englisch, Mnemosyne. Supplementum 171, Leiden, New York und Köln: Brill.

But I don't want LaTeX to print the name of the language ("Englisch" in the example above) but to use it *only for hyphenation*, and though I've been trying everything I've been trying everything for several months, I only found ways either to put each entry in another `otherlanguage`-environment (by passing the option `babel=other` to biblatex) or suppress all infos about the language by putting all known languages in `\DeclareRedundantLanguages{ngerman}{german,english,french,italian,british,franconian,vedic,malaysian ...}`

Another idea was to change the `language`-field in the `.bib`-file to `hyphenation`, but I still got the name of the language in each entry.

Comment: `biblatex` does not use `language` but `hyphenation` to determine the hyphenation language, so you need to use the latter field. If you use `babel=other`, you will have to load the languages in `babel` though. You might be OK with `babel=hyphen`. So your best bet is to change the `language` to `hyphenation` fields. If you want, there is an automatic solution to map `language` to `hyphenation`.

Comment: On second reading through your post, I'm almost certain that what you want is `babel=hyphen` and the `hyphenation` field. Keep in  mind that `hyphenation` takes `babel`/`polyglossia` language identifiers such as `ngerman`, `american` etc.

Comment: You are so -- first, I actually wrote `babel=hyphen`, then biblatex complained and I changed it to `autolang=hyphen`. But nothing changed, neither with `babel=hyphen` nor with `autolang=hyphen` nor after replacing `language =` with `hyphenation =` in the .bib-file. So the first step is to map `language` to `hyphenation` (how do I do it?), but I don't expect it to solve the problem---at least not even `hyphenation` instead of `language` in the (very large: 450 items) .bib-file could prevent `Englisch` in the example above.

Comment: In version 2.7 and before you want `babel=hyphen`, in 2.8 and above it's `autolang` (though `babel` still works). The new name for the `hyphen` field is `langid` (though, again, the old one should still work).

Comment: If you just want to remove the language field, you can do `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}`.  See [biblatex remove the eng. from citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121661)

Comment: Now it works with `langid` (I didn't know it) for `language` in the `.bib`-file! Excellent---but what do I write in the `.tex` file in order to map the `language` field to the `langid` fields in the `.tex` file? I do not want to rewrite the entire `.bib` file.

Comment: There is a way to do that automatically, but one has to be careful with natural language name vs. `babel` language name. One would normally write `language={german}`, while it is better to go with `hyphenation={ngerman}` for new German orthography.

Comment: I actually wrote `language={ngerman}` and mapped it to `german` by writing `\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{ngerman}` (I did the same with `british` and `english`). How do I automatic mapping???

Comment: That's a clever idea! For mapping, see my answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want `biblatex`'s `autolang=hyphen` option (formerly known as `babel=hyphen`).
One has to specify the hyphenation language via the `langid` (formerly [<= 2.7] `hyphenation`) field.

There is a way to automatically map the `language` field to the `langid`  field.
The following lines in the preamble should be enough to do that.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=language, fieldset=langid, origfieldval, final]
      \step[fieldset=language, null]
    }
  }
}
```

This command will copy the `language` field into the `langid` field and will then delete the contents of the `language` field.
The language field will only be deleted if it was successfully copied into the `langid` field.

The caveats in my comment above still apply: In the `language` field one can write `german` or even `langlatin and langgerman`, while the `langid` field should take proper `babel`/`polyglossia` language identifiers (and only one of those; "The identifier must be a language name known to the `babel`/`polyglossia` packages.", §2.2.3, p.24 of the [`biblatex` documentation (v. 2.8)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)). In particular for entries in new German orthography `language` should of course be `german` while `langid` ought to be `ngerman`.

See this MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman,english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autolang=hyphen, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{vangennep:trans,
  author       = {van Gennep, Arnold},
  title        = {The Rites of Passage},
  year         = 1960,
  translator   = {Vizedom, Monika B. and Caffee, Gabrielle L.},
  language     = {english},
  origlanguage = {french},
  publisher    = {University of Chicago Press},
}
@Book{cicero,
  author       = {Cicero, Marcus Tullius},
  title        = {De natura deorum. {\"U}ber das Wesen der G{\"o}tter},
  date         = 1995,
  editor       = {Blank-Sangmeister, Ursula},
  translator   = {Blank-Sangmeister, Ursula},
  afterword    = {Thraede, Klaus},
  language     = {langlatin and langgerman},
  publisher    = {Reclam},
  location     = {Stuttgart},
  hyphenation  = {german},
}
@book{testbook,
  author        = {Walter Ordsmith},
  title         = {The Work},
  subtitle      = {Subtitle},
  year          = {1983},
  publisher     = {P. Ublisher \& Co.},
  address       = {Townsville},
  language      = {german},
}
@article{testart1,
  author  = {Steven C. Ientist and Paula Rofessor},
  title   = {Thrilling, Intelligent and True Limes of Erudition},
  journal = {Journal of Articles},
  volume  = {20},
  number  = {3},
  year    = {1935},
  pages   = {1--46},
  language= {american},
}
@incollection{ordChap3,
  author     = {Walter Ordsmith and William Riter},
  title      = {A Chapter},
  booktitle  = {The Second Work},
  publisher  = {Academic Press},
  year       = {1977},
  language   = {french},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=language, fieldset=langid, origfieldval, final]
      \step[fieldset=language, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. After the first attempt I even wrote                                                       \DeclareSourcemap{
       \maps[datatype=biblatex]{
       \map{
          \step[fieldsource=language, null]
          \step[fieldset=langid, origfieldval]
        }
  }
}`                                                         I still get Bakker _Title_, **Englisch**. Dixsaut, _Title_, **Französisch**.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann Yep, I missed that, I changed the answer. Does it now do what you want?

Comment: If I sum it up: If I write `langid` instead of `language`, the name of the language is not printed (and the hyphenation rules of the language are probably applied), but neither with the original \DeclareSourceMap ...` code nor with the improved one  does anything change.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann I made small change again, on my machine it finally does what you want (technically: the files say it does), though I cannot be sure about application of hyphenation rules (I have no proper test cases, I could spot a difference with).

Comment: Thnkx---one moment.

Comment: I tried it your example and my file with your code snippe: in your MWE it omits the name of the language (translated into german) only in Ordsmith, _The Works_ (where the language is `german`). I even changed your code from datatype=bibtex` to `datatype=biblatex` and `fieldset=hyphenation` to `fieldset=langid` (which doesn't work at all), but nothings changes.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann `datatype=biblatex` will not work, it has to be `datatype=bibtex` (for `.bib` files at least; since the data file is in BibTeX format). I have included a picture of the output on my machine. I'm running version 2.7a though and not 2.8, so I cannot be sure if the new `langid` stuff in v. 2.8 breaks any of the above code. I will update the answer as soon as I have tested it with v. 2.8.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann I just got my hands on version 2.8 and can assure you that the answer above now does what you want on my PC.

Comment: Excellent! It _does_ work, no more annoying Deutsch, Englisch, Italienisch ... I don't see whether the hyphenation actually differs from language to language, as nearly no word is broken across the line. You may sell it biblatex

Comment: The `langid` is in fact only really used if you specify a non-`none` value for the `autolang` option anyway.

Comment: As, for example, with autolang=hyphen? Is that what you mean?                                                      @moewe: BTW: A proof that it sets the entry in the selected language environment without changing the bibliography strings: The string "| in an entry, whose  language is english, appears in the pdf!